# Nutch 1.12 and Solr Integration

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using Nutch 1.12 and Apache Solr 6.2.1.
I crawled the urls using nutch they worked perfectly fine.
But,the issue comes when I try to integrate Nutch with Solr.

I've used the following command

bin/nutch index http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore crawl/crawldb/ -linkdb crawl/linkdb/ crawl/segments/20161123164547/ -filter -normalize -deleteGone

```
The input path at crawldb is not a segment... skipping
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20161123164547.
Indexer: starting at 2016-11-23 20:16:43
Indexer: deleting gone documents: true
Indexer: URL filtering: true
Indexer: URL normalizing: true
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
        solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance
        solr.zookeeper.hosts : URL of the Zookeeper quorum
        solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
        solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
        solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth.username : username for authentication
        solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Indexer: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(                                                                                                                                                                            RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLo                                                                                                                                                                            calFileSystem.java:534)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1697)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:2                                                                                                                                                                            68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java                                                                                                                                                                            :45)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:520)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:512)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:833)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:145)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:237)
```